# Manual Referencing vs. DBRef in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, spring-data-mongodb

I'm still learning MongoDB and it's drivers, so forgive my ignorance.

I understand that Spring Data MongoDB can automatically map something like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5cd4e8140615c7480f549907"),
  "name" : "test",
  "otherCollection" : [ 
    {
      "$ref" : "otherCollection",
      "$id" : ObjectId("5cd4e8140615c7480f549905")
    }
  ]
}
```

It populates my POJO's perfectly, in nested collections. However I tried manual referencing as well, something like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5cd4e8140615c7480f549906"),
  "name" : "test",
  "otherCollection" : [ 
    ObjectId("5cd4e8140615c7480f549905")
  ]
}
```

And this is the error I received

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.types.ObjectId] to type [com.test.test.model.OtherObject]
```

In the docs for Manual Reference it says

```
Then your application can run a second query to return the related data.
```

Now I understand that they literally mean you yourself have to go in and join these in code. Now for DBRef, they have this

```
Some community supported drivers may have alternate behavior and may resolve a DBRef into a document automatically.
```

My question: Is the reason many drivers (like Spring Data MongoDB) resolve DBRefs for you because they are scoped to a single collection? And there's no such thing as manual reference auto-resolution because they would have to scan the whole database instead?

And a follow up, my models contains a finite set of many-to-many relationships which also have a lot of repeated data, so I don't want to embed. Image if the parent-child in the object-array are flipped, need that use case.

So would my choices be

1. Write a custom type convertor for manual referencing in Spring Data MongoDB (is that even a thing?)
2. Use DBRefs for all items in a collection
3. Have a separate relation table that links IDs and query them using `$lookup` (How does performance compare to DBRef?)
4. Don't use MongoDB for lots of many-to-many use cases? Maybe this is the wrong tool for that and I should stick with RDBMS databases?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at *relmongo* framework which allows you to implement relationships using annotations.

Comment: This could have been a comment on the original question.